# html: load formData to populate default values

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I have an HTML form:

```html
    <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/submit" target="response-frame">
        <div class="input">
            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="x" />
        </div>

        <div class="input">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="email@example.com" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="loadValues" onclick="setFormValues()">Load Values</button>
    </form>
```

When I click on submit, the filled in values are sent in the form of a `formData` object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

For some of the form entries, I have default/placeholder values, like e.g. for the email i have the default value: `email@example.com` and when i submit the form, this default value is included in the formdata.

[image]

My question is, is there any way populate my HTML elegantly with an existing formData object?

I know that I could just use a script that populates the form, like I do already to some degree here:

```html
<script>
        function setFormValues() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const key = urlParams.get("key");
            if (key) {
                document.getElementById("name").value = key;
            }
        }

        window.onload = setFormValues;
    </script>
```

But my form will have 15 fields or so, and it seems tedious to set every single of these fields manually, and it seems inelegant to set them via a loop.

Ideally, I would like to just "load an existing formData object" that automatically puts all the default values/placedholders. The user can then modify the fields to their liking, and when they click on send, the modified formData is sent to the destination.

My full code is here: https://github.com/charelF/wg-form-page/blob/main/public/form.html

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example within your post here; links can break and are therefore rendered useless to future readers. Additionally, we shouldn't have to wade through all your code to debug it. What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: `type="loadValues"` is not a valid attribute for a button. The only valid types are `submit`, `button`, and `reset`. Any other value is treated as `submit`.

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing built-in that will do what you want. `FormData` is intended for client->server transmission, not the other way. What's inelegant about a loop?

Comment: _I have default/placeholder values_ - those are very different, placeholder text isn't submitted, default value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URLSearchParams.entries()` and `Array::forEach()`:

```js
[...new URLSearchParams('?name=Alexander%20Nenashev&email=aleks4hour@gmail.com')
  .entries()]
  .forEach(([name, value]) => 
    Object.assign(document.querySelector(`form [name="${ CSS.escape(name) }"]`) ?? {}, {value})
  );
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/submit" target="response-frame">
        <div class="input">
            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="x" />
        </div>

        <div class="input">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="email@example.com" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="loadValues" onclick="setFormValues()">Load Values</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to convert the entries iterator an array: `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).entries(...).forEach is not a function`. And you should makes sure the elements are descendents of that specific form; either by using the ID in the selector, or by performing the selection from a reference to the form element.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes in ff only, chrome confused me

Comment: What's confusing? [`URLSearchParams::entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries) returns an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). Iterators only have methods related to consuming them, which doesn't include `.forEach()`. Therefore, you need to convert it to an array first. For example, `[...iterator]` or `Array.from(iterator)`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator/forEach no support in FF

Comment: Yes, that is part of the Iterator Helpers proposal, which is still experimental. I am on Chrome 116; it is in Chrome 117. Please either **(a)** make demos that work for the majority of users **(b)** use the latest features but include a note about support and changes needed for backwards compatibility **(c)** preferably, make the demo work for the majority but include a note that it can be _simplified_ using new features. Thanks for editing your Snippet :)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes my mistake, no problem